# Applicative parser stuck in infinite loop

Tags: parsing, haskell, infinite-loop, lazy-evaluation, alternative-functor

I'm trying to implement my own Applicative parser, here's the code I use:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ApplicativeDo, LambdaCase #-}

module Parser where

-- Implementation of an Applicative Parser

import Data.Char
import Control.Applicative (some, many, empty, (<*>), (<$>), (<|>), Alternative)

data Parser a = Parser { runParser :: String -> [(a, String)] }

instance Functor Parser where
  -- fmap :: (a -> b) -> (Parser a -> Parser b)
  fmap f (Parser p) = Parser (\s -> [(f a, s') | (a,s') <- p s])

instance Applicative Parser where
  -- pure :: a -> Parser a
  -- <*> :: Parser (a -> b) -> Parser a -> Parser b
  pure x = Parser $ \s -> [(x, s)]
  (Parser pf) <*> (Parser p) = Parser $ \s -> 
               [(f a, s'') | (f, s') <- pf s, (a, s'') <- p s']

instance Alternative Parser where
  -- empty :: Parser a
  -- <|> :: Parser a -> Parser a -> Parser a
  empty = Parser $ \_s -> []
  (Parser p1) <|> (Parser p2) = Parser $ \s ->
      case p1 s of [] -> p2 s
                   xs -> xs

char :: Char -> Parser Char
char c = Parser $ \case (c':cs) | c == c' -> [(c,cs)] ; _ -> []

main = print $ runParser (some $ char 'A') "AAA"
```

When I run it, it gets stuck and never returns. After digging into the problem I pinpointed the root cause to be my implementation of the `<|>` method. If I use the following implementation then everything goes as expected:

```
instance Alternative Parser where
  empty = Parser $ \_s -> []
  p1 <|> p2 = Parser $ \s ->
    case runParser p1 s of [] -> runParser p2 s
                           xs -> xs
```

These two implementations are, in my understanding, quite equivalent. What I guess is that this may have something to do with Haskell's lazy evaluation scheme. Can someone explain what's going on?

Comment: Also, if you're using a list instead of a Maybe, I'd expect your `<|>` implementation to be to call both parsers unconditionally, and combine their results with `(++)`; `(Parser p) <|> (Parser q) = Parser $ (\s -> p s ++ q s)`

Comment: @amalloy: You're right, but either way it will stuck into the same loop.

Comment: @ShouYa It's not just "those two different approaches are conceptually the same", but "you've pasted the exact same code twice and are asking why it only works once".

Comment: @amalloy oops my fault. fixed :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fact "star": in your implementation of `(<*>)`:

```
Parser p1 <*> Parser p2 = ...
```

...we must compute enough to know that both arguments are actually applications of the `Parser` constructor to something before we may proceed to the right-hand side of the equation.

Fact "pipe strict": in this implementation:

```
Parser p1 <|> Parser p2 = ...
```

...we must compute enough to know that both parsers are actually applications of the `Parser` constructor to something before we may proceed to the right-hand side of the equals sign.

Fact "pipe lazy": in this implementation:

```
p1 <|> p2 = Parser $ ...
```

...we may proceed to the right-hand side of the equals sign without doing any computation on `p1` or `p2`.

This is important, because:

```
some v = some_v where
    some_v = pure (:) <*> v <*> (some_v <|> pure [])
```

Let's take your first implementation, the one about which we know the "pipe strict" fact. We want to know if `some_v` is an application of `Parser` to something. Thanks to fact "star", we must therefore know whether `pure (:)`, `v`, and `some_v <|> pure []` are applications of `Parser` to something. To know this last one, by fact "pipe strict", we must know whether `some_v` and `pure []` are applications of `Parser` to something. Whoops! We just showed that to know whether `some_v` is an application of `Parser` to something, we need to know whether `some_v` is an application of `Parser` to something -- an infinite loop!

On the other hand, with your second implementation, to check whether `some_v` is a `Parser _`, we still must check `pure (:)`, `v`, and `some_v <|> pure []`, but thanks to fact "pipe lazy", that's *all* we need to check -- we can be confident that `some_v <|> pure []` is a `Parser _` without first checking recursively that `some_v` and `pure []` are.

(And next, you will learn about `newtype` -- and be confused yet again when changing from `data` to `newtype` makes *both* implementation work!)