# Stack overflow with two functions calling each other in Applicative parser

Tags: parsing, haskell, recursion, functional-programming, stack-overflow

I'm doing data61's course: https://github.com/data61/fp-course. In the parser one, the following implementation will cause `parse (list1 (character *> valueParser 'v')) "abc"` stack overflow.

Existing code:

```
data List t =
  Nil
  | t :. List t
  deriving (Eq, Ord)

-- Right-associative
infixr 5 :.

type Input = Chars

data ParseResult a =
    UnexpectedEof
  | ExpectedEof Input
  | UnexpectedChar Char
  | UnexpectedString Chars
  | Result Input a
  deriving Eq

instance Show a => Show (ParseResult a) where
  show UnexpectedEof =
    "Unexpected end of stream"
  show (ExpectedEof i) =
    stringconcat ["Expected end of stream, but got >", show i, "<"]
  show (UnexpectedChar c) =
    stringconcat ["Unexpected character: ", show [c]]
  show (UnexpectedString s) =
    stringconcat ["Unexpected string: ", show s]
  show (Result i a) =
    stringconcat ["Result >", hlist i, "< ", show a]

instance Functor ParseResult where
  _ <$> UnexpectedEof =
    UnexpectedEof
  _ <$> ExpectedEof i =
    ExpectedEof i
  _ <$> UnexpectedChar c =
    UnexpectedChar c
  _ <$> UnexpectedString s =
    UnexpectedString s
  f <$> Result i a =
    Result i (f a)

-- Function to determine is a parse result is an error.
isErrorResult ::
  ParseResult a
  -> Bool
isErrorResult (Result _ _) =
  False
isErrorResult UnexpectedEof =
  True
isErrorResult (ExpectedEof _) =
  True
isErrorResult (UnexpectedChar _) =
  True
isErrorResult (UnexpectedString _) =
  True

-- | Runs the given function on a successful parse result. Otherwise return the same failing parse result.
onResult ::
  ParseResult a
  -> (Input -> a -> ParseResult b)
  -> ParseResult b
onResult UnexpectedEof _ = 
  UnexpectedEof
onResult (ExpectedEof i) _ = 
  ExpectedEof i
onResult (UnexpectedChar c) _ = 
  UnexpectedChar c
onResult (UnexpectedString s)  _ = 
  UnexpectedString s
onResult (Result i a) k = 
  k i a

data Parser a = P (Input -> ParseResult a)

parse ::
  Parser a
  -> Input
  -> ParseResult a
parse (P p) =
  p

-- | Produces a parser that always fails with @UnexpectedChar@ using the given character.
unexpectedCharParser ::
  Char
  -> Parser a
unexpectedCharParser c =
  P (\_ -> UnexpectedChar c)

--- | Return a parser that always returns the given parse result.
---
--- >>> isErrorResult (parse (constantParser UnexpectedEof) "abc")
--- True
constantParser ::
  ParseResult a
  -> Parser a
constantParser =
  P . const

-- | Return a parser that succeeds with a character off the input or fails with an error if the input is empty.
--
-- >>> parse character "abc"
-- Result >bc< 'a'
--
-- >>> isErrorResult (parse character "")
-- True
character ::
  Parser Char
character = P p
  where p Nil = UnexpectedString Nil
        p (a :. as) = Result as a

-- | Parsers can map.
-- Write a Functor instance for a @Parser@.
--
-- >>> parse (toUpper <$> character) "amz"
-- Result >mz< 'A'
instance Functor Parser where
  (<$>) ::
    (a -> b)
    -> Parser a
    -> Parser b
  f <$> P p = P p'
    where p' input = f <$> p input 

-- | Return a parser that always succeeds with the given value and consumes no input.
--
-- >>> parse (valueParser 3) "abc"
-- Result >abc< 3
valueParser ::
  a
  -> Parser a
valueParser a = P p
  where p input = Result input a

-- | Return a parser that tries the first parser for a successful value.
--
--   * If the first parser succeeds then use this parser.
--
--   * If the first parser fails, try the second parser.
--
-- >>> parse (character ||| valueParser 'v') ""
-- Result >< 'v'
--
-- >>> parse (constantParser UnexpectedEof ||| valueParser 'v') ""
-- Result >< 'v'
--
-- >>> parse (character ||| valueParser 'v') "abc"
-- Result >bc< 'a'
--
-- >>> parse (constantParser UnexpectedEof ||| valueParser 'v') "abc"
-- Result >abc< 'v'
(|||) ::
  Parser a
  -> Parser a
  -> Parser a
P a ||| P b = P c
  where c input
          | isErrorResult resultA = b input
          | otherwise = resultA
            where resultA = a input

infixl 3 |||
```

My code:

```
instance Monad Parser where
  (=<<) ::
    (a -> Parser b)
    -> Parser a
    -> Parser b
  f =<< P a = P p
    where p input = onResult (a input) (\i r -> parse (f r) i)

instance Applicative Parser where
  (<*>) ::
    Parser (a -> b)
    -> Parser a
    -> Parser b
  P f <*> P a = P b
    where b input = onResult (f input) (\i f' -> f' <$> a i)

list ::
  Parser a
  -> Parser (List a)
list p = list1 p ||| pure Nil

list1 ::
  Parser a
  -> Parser (List a)
list1 p = (:.) <$> p <*> list p
```

However, if I change `list` to not use `list1`, or use `=<<` in `list1`, it works fine. It also works if `<*>` uses `=<<`. I feel like it might be an issue with tail recursion.

**UPDATE:**

If I use lazy pattern matching here

```
  P f <*> ~(P a) = P b
    where b input = onResult (f input) (\i f' -> f' <$> a i)
```

It works fine. Pattern matching here is the problem. I don't understand this... Please help!

Comment: As someone who is not familiar with fp-course, this code is hard to understand on its own. Can you try and reduce this to a minimal reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @IzaakWeiss I have removed unrelated code (`pure`)

Comment: @stevemao We're missing the definitions of `Parser`, `onresult`, `parse`, `|||` and `:.`  though. Please make a self-contained example.

Comment: @Bergi missing definitions should be added. Thanks.

Comment: I found the problem and have updated the description. Please help me

Comment: @WillNess The link doesn't mention the difference between `data` and `newtype` in terms of laziness. Do you also have a link to that? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I use lazy pattern matching `P f <*> ~(P a) = ...` then it works fine. Why?

This very issue was [discussed recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58625324/applicative-parser-stuck-in-infinite-loop/58631068#58631068). You could also fix it by using `newtype` instead of `data`: `newtype Parser a = P (Input -> ParseResult a)`.(*)

The definition of `list1` wants to know *both* parser arguments to `<*>`, but actually when the first will fail (when input is exhausted) we don't need to know the second! But since we force it, it will force its second argument, and that one will force its second parser, ad infinitum.(**) That is, `p` *will* fail when input is exhausted, but we have `list1 p = (:.) <$> p <*> list p` which forces `list p` even though it won't run when the preceding `p` fails. That's the reason for the infinite looping, and why your fix with the lazy pattern works.

> What is the difference between `data` and `newtype` in terms of laziness?

(*)`newtype`'d type always has only one data constructor, and pattern matching on it does *not* actually force the value, so it is implicitly like a lazy pattern. Try `newtype P = P Int`, `let foo (P i) = 42 in foo undefined` and see that it works.

(**) This happens when the parser is still prepared, composed; before the combined, composed parser even gets to run on the actual input. This means there's yet another, third way to fix the problem: define

```
list1 p = (:.) <$> p <*> P (\s -> parse (list p) s)
```

This should work regardless of the laziness of `<*>` and whether `data` or `newtype` was used.

Intriguingly, the above definition means that the parser will be actually created during run time, depending on the input, which is the defining characteristic of Monad, not Applicative which is supposed to be known statically, in advance. But the difference here is that the Applicative depends on the hidden state of input, and not on the "returned" value.