# Cascading Parsers in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, applicative

My parser type is

```
newtype Parser a = Parser { parse :: String -> Maybe (a,String) }
```

I have two parsers :

1) `a = (satisfy isAlpha)`  that knows how to match the first alpha  numeric character in a string.

Running **`parse a "k345"`** gives **`Just ('k',"345")`**

2) `b = many (satisfy isDigit)` that  knows how to match any number of digits. Running **`parse b "1234 abc"`** gives **`Just ("1234"," abc")`**

Now I want to combine those two parsers and match a singe alphanumeric character followed by any number of digits.

I tried:

**`parse (a *> b) "k1234 7"`**   and got **`Just ("1234"," 7 ")`**. Looks like the `'k'` matched by the first parser `a` is gone from the output. How do I fix this problem ?

Thanks!

Comment: The semantics of  `*>` is just sequence actions, discarding the value of the first argument. [Look here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-42--62-). Maybe you need something like `Monoid` [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.14.0/docs/Text-Parsec.html).

Comment: you could also try `parse (a <* b) "k1234 7"` and get `Just ('k'," 7")` or `parse (a <*> b) "k1234 7"` and get an error essentially about `'k'` being not a function and the application of `'k'` and `"1234"` being invalid. But `x y = x $ y` whereas what we need here is `x : y`; and since `a <*> b = liftA2 ($) a b`,  `liftA2 (:) a b` is the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a toy parser, look the following code:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
module Parse where

import Data.Char
import Data.List

newtype Parser a = Parser 
  { parse :: String -> Maybe (a, String) }

satisfy :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser Char
satisfy cond = Parser $ \s ->
   case s of 
     "" -> Nothing 
     (c:cs) -> if cond c then Just (c, cs) else Nothing

many :: Parser a -> Parser [a]
many p = Parser $ \s -> 
  case parse p s of 
    Nothing -> Just ([], s)
    Just (c, cs) -> let Just (cc, cs') = parse (many p) cs
                     in Just (c:cc, cs')

string :: String -> Parser String 
string str = Parser $ \s -> if isPrefixOf str s 
                               then Just (str, drop (length str) s)
                               else Nothing

instance Functor Parser where 
  fmap f (Parser g) = Parser $ \s -> 
    case g s of
      Nothing -> Nothing
      Just (r, remain) -> Just (f r, remain)

instance Applicative Parser where
  pure a = Parser $ \s -> Just (a, s)
  -- (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
  (Parser f) <*> (Parser g) = Parser $ \s -> 
    case f s of
      Nothing -> Nothing
      Just (ab, remain) -> case g remain of
                            Nothing -> Nothing
                            Just (r, remain1) -> Just (ab r, remain1)

instance Semigroup a => Semigroup (Parser a) where 
  (Parser p1) <> (Parser p2) = Parser $ \s -> 
    case p1 s of 
      Nothing -> Nothing 
      Just (r1, s1) -> case p2 s1 of 
                         Nothing -> Nothing 
                         Just (r2, s2) -> Just (r1 <> r2, s2)

instance (Monoid a, Semigroup (Parser a))=> Monoid (Parser a) where
  mempty = Parser $ \s -> Just (mempty, s)
  mappend = (<>)

a = satisfy isAlpha
b = many (satisfy isDigit)
```

```
λ> parse a "k345"
Just ('k',"345")
λ> parse b "12345 abc"
Just ("12345"," abc")
λ> parse (a *> b) "k1234 7"
Just ("1234"," 7")
λ> parse (string "k" <> b) "k1234 7"
Just ("k1234"," 7")
```

So maybe you should find some tutorials and try to be familiar with `Functor`, `Applicative`, and `Monad`. See, you can implement the instance of a `Monoid` for your `Parser` type, and then you can use `(<>)` to combine your parsed results together.

Comment: non-lazy patterns in `(Parser f) <*> (Parser g) = ...`  [can be problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58625324/applicative-parser-stuck-in-infinite-loop).

Comment: @WillNess Those patterns are lazy here, believe it or not! Because `Parser` is a newtype constructor, it always matches, unlike the analogous pattern with a data constructor; I even call this out explicitly in the answer at the linked question.

Comment: @DanielWagner ah yes, missed that bit here. (I reference it in my answer at the linked answer's entry's linked entry, :) too :) ). (meta question: did you get notified of my comment somehow, or manually stumbled upon it?)

Comment: rewriting this [with MonadComprehensions](https://pastebin.com/zSgSFcQB) makes it so much clearer. :)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this is working fine :

```
parse  (fmap  (:)  (satisfy isAlpha)  <*>  many (satisfy isDigit))   "k1234 7"
```

And gives back what I wanted

```
Just ("k1234"," 7")
```

Comment: That is correct, but normally that parser would be written as `(:) <$> satisfy isAlpha <*> many (satisfy isDigit)` (`<$>` is just a synonym of `fmap` but as an infix operator), or sometimes as `liftA2 (:) (satisfy isAlpha) $ many (satisfy isDigit)`

Comment: Thanks you!! BTW is there any standard function in Haskell that works the opposite of the cost function, namely take 2 arguments and return the second one ? It would help me learn the relationship between <*> and *>.

Comment: there's always [flip](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:flip), so `flip const` will do what you want. As will `curry snd` (`flip` is the same as `curry fst`). But this doesn't have much to do with `*>` and `<*`, which do *not* behave like constant functions - while they discard the *value* of one of their arguments, they do execute its *effects*. (In the case of a parser, the "effect" in question is that the text parsed by the "ignored" argument is still consumed.)

Comment: I have the single char parser  code

char c = ws *> satisfy (==c)

and for learning I tried to write it using  <*> instead of *> so here is the connection :

char c = flip const <$>  ws  <*> satisfy (==c)

Comment: ws removes spaces