# Weird bugs in a simple monadic parser in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell

I cooked up a simple monadic parser on my own, following [the idea by Hutton and Meijer](https://www.cmi.ac.in/%7Espsuresh/teaching/prgh15/papers/monadic-parsing.pdf).

```hs
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Char

data Parser a = P (String -> [(String, a)])

parse :: Parser a -> String -> [(String, a)]
parse (P p) = p
  
char :: Parser Char
char = P $ \s -> case s of
  [] -> []
  (c:cs) -> [(cs, c)]
  
instance Functor Parser where
  fmap f (P t) = P $ \s -> [ (s, f a) | (s, a) <- t s ]

instance Applicative Parser where
  pure a = P (\s -> [(s, a)])
  P f <*> P a = P $ \s -> [(s, f a) | (s, f) <- f s, (s, a) <- a s]
    
instance Monad Parser where
  P a >>= pf = P $ \s -> [(s, a) | (s, a) <- a s, let P f = pf a, (s, a) <- f s]

instance Alternative Parser where
  empty = P $ \s -> []
  P a <|> P b = P $ \s -> case a s of
                            [] -> b s
                            r -> r
```

It parses fine with eating a single char: `parse char "abc"`, which correctly gives `[("bc",'a')]`. To my surprise, however, it fails when the `many` combinator is used: `parse (many char) "abc"` seems to result in endless loop without printing out anything.

Nevertheless, if I change the definition of `<|>` to the following

```hs
  pa <|> P b = P $ \s -> case parse pa s of
                           [] -> b s
                           r -> r
```

which I think is semantically almost equivalent to the old definition of `<|>`, then everything works normal. `parse (many char) "abc"` gives `[("", "abc")]` as expected.

Alternatively, the bug can also be fixed without changing the definition of `<|>`, but modifying `<*>` as:

```hs
  P f <*> pa = P $ \s -> [(s, f a) | (s, f) <- f s, (s, a) <- parse pa s]
```

which also looks equivalent to the old definition of `<*>`.

Can anyone help to explain these bizarre phenomena?

Comment: Haven't had the time to fully look into this yet, but you're shadowing a lot of variables which makes the code a bit hard to read (and is pretty dangerous in haskell since it's pretty easy to introduce something that _looks_ like shadowing but is actually a recursive definition), als the alternative instance is wrong (probably not the cause here, but your `p1 <|> p2` would crash if `p1` could produce multiple results)

Comment: They are nearly equivalent, but not fully semantically equivalent, as your experiments prove. Indeed, consider `P a <*> undefined`: when the definition of `<*>` immediately pattern matches the second argument, that will crash, but if the pattern matching is deferred to `P (\s -> <<patternMatchHere>>)` then some part of the result is produced before the crash. In recursive definitions, this extra laziness is often what makes the code work without getting stuck in an infinite recursion.

Comment: To stress the point, compare `let p = case p of (x, _) -> (1, x)` to `let p = (1, fst p)`. The former loops/crashes, the latter works thanks to the more lazy definition.

Comment: @Cubic, thanks for your comments but I don't think the too issues you mentioned was causing the problem. (1) The code did contain many shadowing variables but the variables all occur in monadic binding rather than `let`-binding. They didn't cause stuck in evaluation in the fixed code. In fact, my original code doesn't contain any shadowed variables while still getting stuck. It was when writing the post that I simplified the variable names using shadowing. (2) In the edited post, I've changed the definition of `<|>` to remove your concern there.

Comment: Believe it or not, I think this is actually a duplicate. Check out [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58625324/applicative-parser-stuck-in-infinite-loop) and let me know if they help; if so, I'll make the official mark, and if not, then highlighting the difference in your question will make your question easier to answer.